# Best structure/pattern to use for this?

Tags: java, enums

Basically what I want is a JComboBox to have a list of cryptographic algorithms that I have added to my application. When the user selects one from the JComboBox, the selected algorithm is stored in a variable.

I am not really satisfied with my current setup of achieving this...

I have an interface Algorithm as follows:

```
public interface Algorithm {
    public String encrypt(String text, Object[] key);
    public String decrypt(String text, Object[] key);
}
```

I then make specific algorithms that implement this interface and override these methods such as:

```
public class CaesarCipher implements Algorithm {

    @Override
    public String encrypt(String text, Object[] key) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String text, Object[] key) {
        ...
    }      
}
```

Now in my GUI I have a variable and JComboBox like so:

```
private Algorithm selectedAlgorithm;
private JComboBox algorithmsComboBox;
```

I wanted the JComboBox to list all of the different algorithms I've added and I didn't know of the correct way of doing this...

So I made an enum like this:

```
public enum AlgorithmType {

    CAESAR_CIPHER("Caesar Cipher", new CaesarCipher());

    private final String name;
    private final Algorithm algorithm;

    private AlgorithmType(String name, Algorithm algorithm) {
        this.name = name;
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    public Algorithm getAlgorithm() {
        return algorithm;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Then to use with my JComboBox, I did something like this:

```
JComboBox<AlgorithmType> algorithmsComboBox = new JComboBox<AlgorithmType>(AlgorithmType.values());
```

I added an ActionListener to my JComboBox to set the selectedAlgorithm variable to the selected Algorithm:

```
algorithmsComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        selectedAlgorithm = ((AlgorithmType)algorithmComboBox.getSelectedItem()).getAlgorithm();
    }

});
```

This works but I'm not sure if it's good practice to be storing objects like that in enums since all of the objects are unnecessarily created when the enum loads.
Is there a better, more typical method of doing this? I can think of some alternatives like just storing each algorithm in a final array or maybe creating an AlgorithmFactory? Or maybe I should not be creating individual classes for each algorithm and just have one Algorithm class which takes an AlgorithmType as a parameter to the encrypt and decrypt methods?

Thanks.

Comment: What’s the sense of the `enum`? Can’t the `Algorithm` implementations have a `toString()` method? Is it that hard to put an instance per `Algorithm` implementation into an array or `List`? What’s the benefit of the `enum`? I don’t get it.

Comment: I don't know. I thought, in general, that using enums was more preferred over using a constant List to hold data. Using a List would be basically the same as the enum. It would create each Algorithm object in the List even if it hasn't been selected in the JComboBox. There must be a better, more efficient method?

Comment: If the resources of `Algorithm` instances are your concern, make `AlgorithmType` a factory that creates an `Algorithm` instance on demand. `AlgorithmType` may be an `enum` (recall that enums can implement interfaces) but it doesn’t have to. I personally prefer keeping open the option of extending the list (maybe even dynamically) in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend storing an object in an Enum. Instead, I would suggest making a Map of Key Value Pair and using the Enum as the Key and the Algorithm as the Value. For specifics look at `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>`.

Answer (score 0):

If ur looking for a pattern try out [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), otherwise if the object thats implements Algorithm dont change at runtime try [Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.